# The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause() - when calling play too quick

Tags: flutter

I've a button that playes a sound when clicked with the help of the AudioPlayers library. But when I spam click the button, I get the error:

```
The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().
    at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:53960/dart_sdk.js:5076:12)
    at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:53960/dart_sdk.js:40477:16)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:53960/dart_sdk.js:40473:13)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:53960/dart_sdk.js:40330:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:53960/dart_sdk.js:40336:13)
    at http://localhost:53960/dart_sdk.js:35811:9
```

Here's the code:

```
AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();

on_pressed(){
  player.play("assets/sound.mp3");
}
```

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
on_pressed : () async {
 await player.play("assets/sound.mp3");
}
```

you aren't using any handler to stop the user from further tapping, one-time tap is enough, you should use some logic to disable the tap until the audio player starts playing.

Comment: No, I'm making a game where you have to spam click a button. So disabling the button unitl it finishes playing would be pointless. I still get the same error occasionally :(

Comment: could there be a way the new recording stops/override the old recording?

Comment: then try using isolates in flutter, that way you can use multi-threading in flutter by assigning asynchronous computing calls on other thread.

Comment: Refer to this 
https://medium.com/flutter-community/thread-and-isolate-with-flutter-30b9631137f3#:~:text=Isolates,in%20its%20own%20memory%20space.